# C# equivalent to Java's Arrays.fill() method

Tags: c#, java, arrays

I'm using the following statement in Java:

```
Arrays.fill(mynewArray, oldArray.Length, size, -1);
```

Please suggest the C# equivalent.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.fill?view=netcore-3.1, also dotnet provide the same function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know of anything in the framework which does that, but it's easy enough to implement:

```
// Note: start is inclusive, end is exclusive (as is conventional
// in computer science)
public static void Fill<T>(T[] array, int start, int end, T value)
{
    if (array == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    }
    if (start < 0 || start >= end)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("fromIndex");
    }
    if (end >= array.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("toIndex");
    }
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        array[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Or if you want to specify the count instead of the start/end:

```
public static void Fill<T>(T[] array, int start, int count, T value)
{
    if (array == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    }
    if (count < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");
    }
    if (start + count >= array.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");
    }
    for (var i = start; i < start + count; i++)
    {
        array[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope my edit is justified.. or otherwise name variable to `uptoIndex`

Comment: @nawfal: No, it was deliberately (although not consistently) exclusive. I've tidied it up and added an alternative.

Comment: Jon, why do you check for exceptional cases and throw yourself when the clr would do that? I'm a bit puzzled by this kind of design. Wouldn't only the second conditional check (in both your examples) alone suffice?

Comment: @nawfal: The CLR will throw different exceptions. Given that these are method arguments, the exceptions thrown should be ArgumentExceptions, IMO. That shows that it's the calling code at fault, not a problem within the method itself.

Comment: @JonSkeet, it is a little bit too late... still a thought: negative count will not cause an exception in the loop... throwing on negative count or on inverted start and stop needs to be well justified...

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you would like to do something more like this

```
int[] bar = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int newSize = 10;
int[] foo = Enumerable.Range(0, newSize).Select(i => i < bar.Length ? bar[i] : -1).ToArray();
```

Creating an new larger array with the old values and filling the extra.

For a simple fill try

```
int[] foo = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => -1).ToArray();
```

or a sub range

```
int[] foo = new int[10];
Enumerable.Range(5, 9).Select(i => foo[i] = -1);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try like this

```
Array.Copy(source, target, 5);
```

For more information [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-copy)

Comment: That doesn't do the same thing as `fill`.

Comment: but it is not target array to copy...it is taking length..mynewArray is int[]

Comment: Rasel's suggestion is ok. Working example:

    int[] arr=new int[1000];
    Array.Copy(arr.Select (i => 5).ToArray(),arr, arr.Length);